# make image point toward specific location in java

Tags: java, rotation, graphics2d

**BEFORE YOU MARK IT AS DUPLICATE**

I have searched a lot in the internet for that and tried every solution, but no one does it the same way I do it. In my case the rotation is in a sperate class.

I have created a java class that inherits `JLabel` class, in my class I have an arrow `BufferedImage` which I draw using the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.

I am trying to make the arrow point to a specific point (which I get from a different method) but something goes wrong and the arrow rotates to the wrong direction.

**I THINK:** it doesn't calculate correctly because the  imageLocation is relative to the label.

Here is my code:

```
package pkg1;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public final class ImageLabel extends JLabel {

   private float angle = 0.0f; // in radians
   private Point imageLocation = new Point();
   private File imageFile = null;
   private Dimension imageSize = new Dimension(50, 50);
   private BufferedImage bi;

   private BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int img_width, int img_height) {
      int type = originalImage.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();
      BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(img_width, img_height, type);
      Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
      g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, img_width, img_height, null);
      g.dispose();

      return resizedImage;
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (bi == null) {
         return;
      }
      imageLocation = new Point(getWidth() / 2 - bi.getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2 - bi.getHeight() / 2);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.rotate(angle, imageLocation.x + bi.getWidth() / 2, imageLocation.y + bi.getHeight() / 2);
      g2.drawImage(bi, imageLocation.x, imageLocation.y, null);
   }

   public void rotateImage(float angle) { // rotate the image to specific angle
      this.angle = (float) Math.toRadians(angle);
      repaint();
   }

   public void pointImageToPoint(Point target) {
      calculateAngle(target);
      repaint();
   }

   private void calculateAngle(Point target) {
      // calculate the angle from the center of the image
      float deltaY = target.y - (imageLocation.y + bi.getHeight() / 2);
      float deltaX = target.x - (imageLocation.x + bi.getWidth() / 2);
      angle = (float) Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
      if (angle < 0) {
         angle += (Math.PI * 2);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Writing **BEFORE YOU MARK IT AS DUPLICATE** is likely a sure-fire way to get marked as a duplicate :)

Comment: ... and a downvote.

Comment: *"I THINK: it doesn't calculate correctly because the imageLocation is relative to the label"* - It might (but I don't think it is), but are you taking into consideration the difference coordinate systems been used - in what component space are the points been calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so two things jump out at me...

1. If you take a `Point` from outside the context of the label, you will have to translate the point into the components coordinate context
2. The `calculateAngle` seems wrong

So starting with...

```
private void calculateAngle(Point target) {
  // calculate the angle from the center of the image
  float deltaY = target.y - (imageLocation.y + bi.getHeight() / 2);
  float deltaX = target.x - (imageLocation.x + bi.getWidth() / 2);
  angle = (float) Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
  if (angle < 0) {
     angle += (Math.PI * 2);
  }
}
```

`angle = (float) Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);` should be `angle = (float) Math.atan2(deltaX, deltaY);` (swap the deltas)

You will find that you need to adjust the result by 180 degrees in order to get the image to point in the right direction

```
angle = Math.toRadians(Math.toDegrees(angle) + 180.0);
```

Okay, I'm an idiot, but it works :P

I'd also make use of a `AffineTransform` to translate and rotate the image - personally, I find it easier to deal with.

In the example, I've cheated a little.  I set the translation of the `AffineTransform` to the centre of the component, I then rotate the context around the new origin point (`0x0`).  I then paint the image offset by half it's height/width, thus making it appear as the if the image is been rotated about it's centre - It's late, I'm tired, it works :P

[image: Point at me]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private ImageLabel label;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new ImageLabel();
            add(label);

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    label.pointImageToPoint(e.getPoint(), TestPane.this);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public final class ImageLabel extends JLabel {

        private double angle = 0;
        private Point imageLocation = new Point();
        private File imageFile = null;
        private Dimension imageSize = new Dimension(50, 50);
        private BufferedImage bi;

        public ImageLabel() {
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
            bi = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawLine(25, 0, 25, 50);
            g2d.drawLine(25, 0, 0, 12);
            g2d.drawLine(25, 0, 50, 12);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());
        }

        protected Point centerPoint() {
            return new Point(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (bi == null) {
                return;
            }
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            AffineTransform at = g2d.getTransform();
            Point center = centerPoint();
            at.translate(center.x, center.y);
            at.rotate(angle, 0, 0);
            g2d.setTransform(at);
            g2d.drawImage(bi, -bi.getWidth() / 2, -bi.getHeight() / 2, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public void rotateImage(float angle) { // rotate the image to specific angle
            this.angle = (float) Math.toRadians(angle);
            repaint();
        }

        public void pointImageToPoint(Point target, JComponent fromContext) {
            calculateAngle(target, fromContext);
            repaint();
        }

        private void calculateAngle(Point target, JComponent fromContext) {
            // calculate the angle from the center of the image
            target = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(fromContext, target, this);
            Point center = centerPoint();
            float deltaY = target.y - center.y;
            float deltaX = target.x - center.x;
            angle = (float) -Math.atan2(deltaX, deltaY);
            angle = Math.toRadians(Math.toDegrees(angle) + 180.0);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to add that using a `JLabel` for this purpose is overkill, a simple `JPanel` or `JComponent` would do the same job and carry a lot less overhead with it, just saying